# How to show arp table of openvswitch?

Tags: arp, openvswitch

I think openvswitch should be similar to a three-layer switch implemented at the software level? The Layer 3 switch supports displaying the arp cache table, such as using the command `dis arp vlan <ID>`, then how does openvswitch achieve the same effect? I tried the command `ovs-dpctl dump-flows`, which can print out the flow of arp request, as well as the correspondence between ip and mac address, but the function of displaying arp table was not found.

Comment: No, `fdb/show` onlyl show mac table, no ips.